# Map in C++ give the key and get the string

Tags: c++, c++11, compiler-errors, maps, syntax-error

I have ***created a map*** like this :   `std::map<int, std::string> mapID;`

***INPUT:*** mapID[1] = "string!";

and I want to print element with the key is the s. 
For example

```
cout << "The string is : " << mapID.at(s)->second << endl;
```

OR

```
cout << "The string is : " << mapID.find(s)->second << endl;
```

But I have the error

> error: no matching function for call to ‘std::map >::at(std::string&)’

***UPDATE:***

```
while(getline(file,s)) 
                   {
                           cout<< s << endl;
                           number = atoi(s.c_str());

                         cout << "The string is: " << mapID.at(number)<< endl;
}
```

Comment: please show a [mcve]. `1` obviously is not a string, so there is something fishy but we need to see more code to reproduce the problem

Comment: mapID[1] will create an element at 1 if it doesn't exist

Comment: Your listed code cannot produce the given error message.  Please show us the actual code, or the actual error message.  (Preferably as a [mcve] that we can cut and paste into (eg) cpp.sh.)

Comment: You have an error about calling `std::map::at(std::string&)`, but there is no such call in the code you've shown to us. What is your actual code?

Comment: @DAle actually is not a 1 but is the argument.

Comment: sorry, but your edit made it worse. Now there is just one more variable that we would have to guess what it is

Comment: ...ufff you dont call `mapID.at(number)` ...

Comment: All the fuze for nothing, next time check please. This is a silly error

Comment: vote to close because it is just a typo

Comment: But I didn't find the solution yet... @tobi303

Comment: @RafoulaRaf then take a break, then look at your code again, if you dont see the problem then explain it to your rubber duck, the error message could not be more clear

Comment: btw your update isnt "extra detailed". It is just the opposite: It is still impossible to reproduce the error you describe with that code (without having to guess). Please read about [mcve]

Comment: @tobi303 sorry, but I can't delete this question..

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the reference http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/at you will see, that method "at" returns a second element of pair. In your case it is std::string.

The code should be

```
cout << "The string is : " << mapID.at(1) << endl;
```

Comment: true, but it doesnt explain the error message reported

Comment: The error message is explained observing that the method `at()` receive a key value, so in `std::map<int, std::string>`, it's available `at(int const &)`, not `at(std::string const &)`

Answer (score -1):

Since C++11, `.at()` returns a reference to the mapped value of the element identified with key k.

Your example was good if you used an iterator as you can then access your pair element made by your map.

Here is an example with an iterator

```
auto it = mapID.find(1);
cout << "The string is : " << it->second << endl;
```

OR with `.at()`

```
cout << "The string is : " << mapID.at(1) << endl;
```

But beware that .at() will throw if the element is not found in your map as it can't create it like the `[]` operator

Comment: assuming OP gets the error message they report, they would still get the same error message with this "fix". (btw same applies to the other "answers"). Whats the point of rushing with answers when the question isnt clear at all??

Comment: @tobi303 _"Whats the point of rushing"_ FGITW as it ever was :P ...

Comment: @tobi303 He called ->second on an std::string element instead of an iterator, that was his mistake, I explain it in my answer

Comment: @rak007 I dont know how to produce the reported error message by calling `->second` on a `string`, if you can explain that, it should be part of the answer

Comment: I was pointing out that what seemed to be the mistake he did in what he had given us as an example